# Modo de algoritmo de cifrado no seguro - Mejora en Descifrado

Tags: java, android-studio, google-play-console

Otro usuario hizo esta pregunta:

[Modo de algoritmo de cifrado no seguro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/583165/modo-de-algoritmo-de-cifrado-no-seguro)

en donde el le doy la respuesta al Cifrado... pero luego me pregunta como puede hacer un descifrado del mismo contenido basándose en mi propuesta?

---

***Propuesta (por si acaso en algun momento deja de verse el link original):***

```
private static final String AES = "AES";
private static final String password = "miclaveparaPBKDF2";
private static final int iterations = 10000;
private static final int keyLength = 256;

private static SecretKey generateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    char[] chars = password.toCharArray();
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    random.nextBytes(salt);
    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(chars, salt, iterations, keyLength);
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    byte[] keyBytes = skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
    return new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, AES);
}

private static String encrypt(String mensajeTexto) {
    SecretKey secretKey = null;
    byte[] encryptedData = new byte[0];
    try {
        secretKey = generateKey();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(mensajeTexto.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Error",ex.getMessage());
    }
    return Base64.encodeToString(encryptedData, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la idea del descifrado es hacer exactamente lo opuesto al cifrado, eso lo podemos lograr incluyendo este método:

```
private static String decrypt(String mensajeCifrado) {
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), AES);
    byte[] decryptedData = new byte[0];
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] encryptedData = Base64.decode(mensajeCifrado, Base64.DEFAULT);
        decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Error",ex.getMessage());
    }
    return new String(decryptedData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

como podemos ver solo se pasa como argumento `mensajeCifrado`

Comment: Je, Error key is not defined!!! in line 2 in function decrypt.